# Azure Functions Deployment Slots best practice - App Plan also swaps on slots swap

Tags: azure, azure-functions

### Context

There is a Function App that runs on Consumption plan
There are two slots (prod + uat) created for the app
Function App and deployment slots have been created using Azure Portal, so all settings were set to default - most important one: two different instances of Consumption plan (Consumption-Plan-01 + Consumption-Plan-02) were created. The reason is - do not share same Consumption plan limits - the app creates many outbound HTTPS connections.

### Problem

On every swap plans are also swap - plan that was used for uat slot now becomes the prod plan and vice versa

### Question

Is this behavior expected?
Can I disable this plan change somehow? Uat slot might be using extensively some resources like Connection to test everything, so I want it to stay on uat slot always...

### Update

Here is an example of slots and plans for my app in portal
[image: Example]

What is a best practice here?

Really appreciate your advices
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First, the Function app on the consumption plan does not have multiple slots, it has only one slot allowed.

Next, if you are on a dedicated app service plan, one app service plan can have up to 5 deployment slots inside the same App service plan. So there are no different app service plans for each slot.

All 5 slots use the same resources and configuration as the main production app. Basically, they share the app service plan.

Please review this to understand better:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/azure-samples/function-app-arm-templates/function-app-deployment-slot/

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. My question was specifically about consumption plan. I've added pic in the original post - prod function + additional slot (2 slots on Consumption plan). On the picture you can see two different instances of Plan with the same type - Consumption.
The weird part for me is that these plans swap as well on slots swap. Is this expected? Shouldn't they stay each on their slot...?